# Windows BLE restrictions?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use `Windows native BLE` to change the device information

- ModelName
- SerialNumber
- HardwareVersion

on the bluetooth device we are developing. This can be done using iOS apps or third party BLE devices but not on Windows native. Is the native BLE stack blocking writes to certain characteristics?

Attempts to write data to e.g. `UID 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (ModelName)` returns `access denied` but the command never reaches the device. Using nRF on iOS the value is written and accepted by the device.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/device-information-service-1-1/) only `read` is mandatory for "Model Number String"(`00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`) of the "Device Information Service" and no optional properties are specified. It is likely that the Microsoft engineers followed the specification very closely.

The situation is different with the "Device Name"(`00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`). This value can optionally also be written.

Have you perhaps mixed up the two UUIDs?

Comment: Tha properties for the characteristic is Read and WriteWithoutResponse. That should be what determines access (IMO). We would like to set model name and serialnumber after assembly and test of the complete device, but maybe I have to do it another way.